# dynamic scale_y_continuous for dynamic axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

having scanned everything I can find on scale_y_continuous is there are way to achieve the following:

Dynamic y axis for survey data where limits change for % and mean result.
P is a % value and the axis needs to be set at 0 - 100
M is a mean value and needs to be set at 1 - 6

This would be really easy if all values were in the same plot; however I have two graphs together in a ggarrange and the second graph has values that are less than the first and the bars are not aligned.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                 P = c(42, 98, 77.5),
                 M = c(2,3.4,5.5)
                 )
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=P)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Is there a way to set scale_y_continuous for P to c(0,100), and for M c(0.6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get one plot based on user input choice we can do :

```
library(ggplot2)
choice = 'P'

if(choice == 'P') {
  p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=P)) + geom_col() + 
              scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
} else {
  p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=M)) + geom_col() + 
          scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6))
}
p1
```

---

To get both the plots together :

You can set `limits` for individual plots using `scale_y_continuous` before combining them in `ggarrange`.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=P)) + geom_col() + 
           scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
p2 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=M)) + geom_col() + 
           scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6))
ggpubr::ggarrange(p1, p2)
```

[image]

However, you can also consder using facets with different y-axis :

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(P, M)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(dose, value) + geom_col()  +
  facet_wrap(.~name, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Ronak, but the axis will be either M or P they will not be in the same graph if that makes sense? So there will be a drop down to select to show either M or P but not both.

Comment: Ohh..I see. But if you don't give any values in `scale_y_continuous` doesn't it select the relevant values on y-axis automatically? If you still want to assign limits manually you can do this conditionally. Let's say you have user's choice in variable `choice` and then use `if`/`else` condition to set limit accordingly. Something like this `if(choice == 'P')` `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))` or `else scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6))`. Would that work?

Comment: Yep that would work, I couldnt figure out how to get an if statement to work though. Would something like this work: if(dataset$measure == 'P'), scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))

Comment: Thanks so much Ronak, greatly appreciated.